# Extract mentioned users in post like Facebook comment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I followed this Laracast tutorial - https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/56 - to get "mentions" inside body. However I now want to fetch all the data for a thread, so I want all posts, and all related users, specifically mentioned users.

I am fetching all posts like this:

```
public function get(Thread $thread) {
    return $thread->with(['posts'=>function($query) { return $query->with('user'); }]);
}
```

This returns to me data like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "posts": [
         {
              "id": 1,
              "user_id": 13,
              "body": "Hi @14 and @15",
              "user": {
                  "id": 13,
                  "name": "Joe"
              }
         },
         {
              "id": 2,
              "user_id": 14,
              "body": "Hi back at you"
              "user": {
                  "id": 14,
                  "name": "Bob"
              }
         }
     ]

}
```

We see I get the author user's just fine. But I also need the mentioend users.

We see in the first one, during the store process, I converted `@string` to `@USER_ID`.

I did this in the store:

```
preg_match_all('/\@[^\s\.]+)/', $post->body, $matches);
```

And repalced with user_id.

Now however on fetch, I want to extract the user_id's from the post and attach to the resulting data these `user`s. Is this possible?

My goal:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "posts": [
         {
              "id": 1,
              "user_id": 13,
              "body": "Hi @14 and @15",
              "users": [
                   {
                       "id": 13,
                       "name": "Joe"
                   },
                   {
                       "id": 14,
                       "name": "Bob"
                   },
                   {
                       "id": 15,
                       "name": "Ryan"
                   }
         },
         {
              "id": 2,
              "user_id": 14,
              "body": "Hi back at you",
         }
     ]

}
```

Is there a way to run the regex on each body and select the mentioned users too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your goal isn't the correct one. You should think a good database design.

In your case, It's good to have `mentions` relation in your `post` (not `users`). Then you can attach the mentioned users to the post `mentions`. Something like,

```
preg_match_all('/\@[^\s\.]+)/', $post->body, $matches);

// get the author of the post
$author = $request->user();

// get all the user account for every @, except the author itself
$mentions = User::where(function ($query) use ($matches) {
    foreach ($matches as $item) {
        $query->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', $item);
    }
})->where('id', '!=', $author->id)->get();

// attach the author to the post
$post->user()->save($author);

// attach $mentions to the post
$post->mentions()->saveMany($mentions);

// notify user were mentioned
Notification::send($mentions, new YouWereMentioned($post));
```

then to fetch the posts, you can do like so,

```
public function get(Thread $thread) {
    return $thread->with([
        'posts'=> function($query) {
            return $query->with('user', 'mentions');
        }
    ]);
}
```

***Note.*** The laracasts video is only for the subscriber. You shouldn't make a question using a private resource. Or you must explain it all.

Comment: Thanks very much I think you're right I'm going to use this solution and setup some relation,  thanks so much for such a great idea, and even including Notifications! :) By chance though would you be able to add how I can supplement query data, of a query, as asked above. But accepted the solution. :)

Comment: Do you mean like that? Updated.

Comment: Thanks @nmfzone I think reorganizing them into relations was definitely the way to go.